# Why doesn't team size affect scrum time-boxing for meetings?

Tags: scrum

Although most time-boxed meetings take the amount of weeks in a sprint into consideration, none of them seems to include the number of team members when calculating the max duration.

What I mean by time-boxed meetings: Sprint Planning, Sprint Review, Daily Scrum, ... - not the sprint itself.

Let's compare a team of 3 to one with 9 members.

According to Scrum we have at max 15 minutes to all answer the '3 big questions' during daily scrum - no matter if we're 3 or 9 people.

Same goes for the sprint review. 9 team members might produce triple the value that 3 do, but again we have 1 hour per week of sprint.

What I would expect is something like
max duration of a sprint review = #ofWeeksInSprint * #ofTeamMembers * someHourConstant.

Why does scrum ignore this factor?

Comment: I thought *velocity* was supposed to handle this.

Comment: Velocity handles the workload and estimate measure, not the meeting lengths.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're taking scrum to be a set of instructions you need to follow to the letter - and it's not meant to be. The time boxes are there to give you an idea on the typical situation. 9 developers in a standup may not work for the estimates they gave: if so, increase your timebox!

The important part of the time box is to make people realize that there *is* an upper limit on how long they can go, keeping the filibusters to a minimum. Try it for a week and see if the amount of time you gave yourself is reasonable - if it's too long, shorten it, if you keep running out of breath to fit it in, make it longer.

Remember, [Individuals and interactions over processes and tools](http://www.agilemanifesto.org/). If your process is keeping you from interacting better, change your process!

Comment: I'm aware that Scrum isn't a set of laws that we must abide, no matter the circumstances. I'm merely wondering why the weeks in a sprint are worth factoring in and the team size isn't. Especially since for both the min-max ratio is about the same (1-4 weeks recommended for a sprint: 4x, 3-9 members a team: 3x). I thought there might be a reason for this,... Thx for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

For all other meetings, [the scrum guide specifies a timebox assuming a month-long sprints but says that the meeting is "usually shorter" for shorter sprints](http://scrumguides.org/scrum-guide.html#events). The only meeting without that provision is the daily scrum. What that tells me is that the daily scrum is timeboxed at 15 minutes for a team of 9 developers, but can be shorter for smaller teams. So a team of three developers might be able to get through their discussion in five minutes, and that's fine. They might need to take all 15 minutes, and that's also fine.